# Personal name of God?

Tags: allah, names

Christians and Jews always accuse Muslims of not having a personal name for God. They say that "Allah" just means "The God", whereas YHWH is a personal name for God.

Do we have a personal name for God?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We have 99 as a matter of fact.

1 ٱلْرَّحْمَـانُ    AR-RAHMAAN  The Most or Entirely Merciful 
2   ٱلْرَّحِيْمُ    AR-RAHEEM   The Bestower of Mercy 
3   ٱلْمَلِكُ   AL-MALIK    The King and Owner of Dominion 
4   ٱلْقُدُّوسُ AL-QUDDUS   The Absolutely Pure 
5   ٱلْسَّلَامُ AS-SALAM    The Perfection and Giver of Peace 
6   ٱلْمُؤْمِنُ AL-MU’MIN   The One Who gives Emaan and Security 
7   ٱلْمُهَيْمِنُ   AL-MUHAYMIN The Guardian, The Witness, The Overseer 
8   ٱلْعَزِيزُ  AL-AZEEZ    The All Mighty 
9   ٱلْجَبَّارُ AL-JABBAR   The Compeller, The Restorer 
10  ٱلْمُتَكَبِّرُ  AL-MUTAKABBIR   The Supreme, The Majestic 
11  ٱلْخَالِقُ  AL-KHAALIQ  The Creator, The Maker 
12  ٱلْبَارِئُ  AL-BAARI’   The Originator 
13  ٱلْمُصَوِّرُ    AL-MUSAWWIR The Fashioner 
14  ٱلْغَفَّارُ AL-GHAFFAR  The All- and Oft-Forgiving 
15  ٱلْقَهَّارُ AL-QAHHAR   The Subduer, The Ever-Dominating 
16  ٱلْوَهَّابُ AL-WAHHAAB  The Giver of Gifts 
17  ٱلْرَّزَّاقُ    AR-RAZZAAQ  The Provider 
18  ٱلْفَتَّاحُ AL-FATTAAH  The Opener, The Judge 
19  ٱلْعَلِيمُ  AL-‘ALEEM   The All-Knowing, The Omniscient 
20  ٱلْقَابِضُ  AL-QAABID   The Withholder 
21  ٱلْبَاسِطُ  AL-BAASIT   The Extender 
22  ٱلْخَافِضُ  AL-KHAAFIDH The Reducer, The Abaser 
23  ٱلْرَّافِعُ AR-RAAFI’   The Exalter, The Elevator 
24  ٱلْمُعِزُّ  AL-MU’IZZ   The Honorer, The Bestower 
25  ٱلْمُذِلُّ  AL-MUZIL    The Dishonorer, The Humiliator 
26  ٱلْسَّمِيعُ AS-SAMEE’   The All-Hearing 
27  ٱلْبَصِيرُ  AL-BASEER   The All-Seeing 
28  ٱلْحَكَمُ   AL-HAKAM    The Judge, The Giver of Justice 
29  ٱلْعَدْلُ   AL-‘ADL The Utterly Just 
30  ٱلْلَّطِيفُ AL-LATEEF   The Subtle One, The Most Gentle 
31  ٱلْخَبِيرُ  AL-KHABEER  The Acquainted, the All-Aware 
32  ٱلْحَلِيمُ  AL-HALEEM   The Most Forbearing 
33  ٱلْعَظِيمُ  AL-‘ATHEEM  The Magnificent, The Supreme 
34  ٱلْغَفُورُ  AL-GHAFOOR  The Forgiving, The Exceedingly Forgiving 
35  ٱلْشَّكُورُ ASH-SHAKOOR The Most Appreciative 
36  ٱلْعَلِيُّ  AL-‘ALEE    The Most High, The Exalted 
37  ٱلْكَبِيرُ  AL-KABEER   The Greatest, The Most Grand 
38  ٱلْحَفِيظُ  AL-HAFEEDH  The Preserver, The All-Heedful and All-Protecting 
39  ٱلْمُقِيتُ  AL-MUQEET   The Sustainer 
40  ٱلْحَسِيبُ  AL-HASEEB   The Reckoner, The Sufficient 
41  ٱلْجَلِيلُ  AL-JALEEL   The Majestic 
42  ٱلْكَرِيمُ  AL-KAREEM   The Most Generous, The Most Esteemed 
43  ٱلْرَّقِيبُ AR-RAQEEB   The Watchful 
44  ٱلْمُجِيبُ  AL-MUJEEB   The Responsive One 
45  ٱلْوَاسِعُ  AL-WAASI’   The All-Encompassing, the Boundless 
46  ٱلْحَكِيمُ  AL-HAKEEM   The All-Wise 
47  ٱلْوَدُودُ  AL-WADOOD   The Most Loving 
48  ٱلْمَجِيدُ  AL-MAJEED   The Glorious, The Most Honorable 
49  ٱلْبَاعِثُ  AL-BA’ITH   The Resurrector, The Raiser of the Dead 
50  ٱلْشَّهِيدُ ASH-SHAHEED The All- and Ever Witnessing 
51  ٱلْحَقُّ    AL-HAQQ The Absolute Truth 
52  ٱلْوَكِيلُ  AL-WAKEEL   The Trustee, The Disposer of Affairs 
53  ٱلْقَوِيُّ  AL-QAWIYY   The All-Strong 
54  ٱلْمَتِينُ  AL-MATEEN   The Firm, The Steadfast 
55  ٱلْوَلِيُّ  AL-WALIYY   The Protecting Associate 
56  ٱلْحَمِيدُ  AL-HAMEED   The Praiseworthy 
57  ٱلْمُحْصِيُ AL-MUHSEE   The All-Enumerating, The Counter 
58  ٱلْمُبْدِئُ AL-MUBDI    The Originator, The Initiator 
59  ٱلْمُعِيدُ  AL-MU’ID    The Restorer, The Reinstater 
60  ٱلْمُحْيِى  AL-MUHYEE   The Giver of Life 
61  ٱلْمُمِيتُ  AL-MUMEET   The Bringer of Death, the Destroyer 
62  ٱلْحَىُّ    AL-HAYY The Ever-Living 
63  ٱلْقَيُّومُ AL-QAYYOOM  The Sustainer, The Self-Subsisting 
64  ٱلْوَاجِدُ  AL-WAAJID   The Perceiver 
65  ٱلْمَاجِدُ  AL-MAAJID   The Illustrious, the Magnificent 
66  ٱلْوَاحِدُ  AL-WAAHID   The One 
67  ٱلْأَحَد    AL-AHAD The Unique, The Only One 
68  ٱلْصَّمَدُ  AS-SAMAD    The Eternal, Satisfier of Needs 
69  ٱلْقَادِرُ  AL-QADIR    The Capable, The Powerful 
70  ٱلْمُقْتَدِرُ   AL-MUQTADIR The Omnipotent 
71  ٱلْمُقَدِّمُ    AL-MUQADDIM The Expediter, The Promoter 
72  ٱلْمُؤَخِّرُ    AL-MU’AKHKHIR   The Delayer, the Retarder 
73  ٱلأَوَّلُ   AL-AWWAL    The First 
74  ٱلْآخِرُ    AL-AAKHIR   The Last 
75  ٱلْظَّاهِرُ AZ-DHAAHIR  The Manifest 
76  ٱلْبَاطِنُ  AL-BAATIN   The Hidden One, Knower of the Hidden 
77  ٱلْوَالِي   AL-WAALI    The Governor, The Patron 
78  ٱلْمُتَعَالِي   AL-MUTA’ALI The Self Exalted 
79  ٱلْبَرُّ    AL-BARR The Source of Goodness, the Kind Benefactor 
80  ٱلْتَّوَّابُ    AT-TAWWAB   The Ever-Pardoning, The Relenting 
81  ٱلْمُنْتَقِمُ   AL-MUNTAQIM The Avenger 
82  ٱلْعَفُوُّ  AL-‘AFUWW   The Pardoner 
83  ٱلْرَّؤُفُ  AR-RA’OOF   The Most Kind 
84  مَالِكُ ٱلْمُلْكُ   MAALIK-UL-MULK  Master of the Kingdom, Owner of the Dominion 
85  ذُو ٱلْجَلَالِ وَٱلْإِكْرَامُ   DHUL-JALAALI WAL-IKRAAM Possessor of Glory and Honor, Lord of Majesty and Generosity 
86  ٱلْمُقْسِطُ AL-MUQSIT   The Equitable, the Requiter 
87  ٱلْجَامِعُ  AL-JAAMI’   The Gatherer, the Uniter 
88  ٱلْغَنيُّ   AL-GHANIYY  The Self-Sufficient, The Wealthy 
89  ٱلْمُغْنِيُّ    AL-MUGHNI   The Enricher 
90  ٱلْمَانِعُ  AL-MANI’    The Withholder 
91  ٱلْضَّارُ   AD-DHARR    The Distresser 
92  ٱلْنَّافِعُ AN-NAFI’    The Propitious, the Benefactor 
93  ٱلْنُّورُ   AN-NUR  The Light, The Illuminator 
94  ٱلْهَادِي   AL-HAADI    The Guide 
95  ٱلْبَدِيعُ  AL-BADEE’   The Incomparable Originator 
96  ٱلْبَاقِي   AL-BAAQI    The Ever-Surviving, The Everlasting 
97  ٱلْوَارِثُ  AL-WAARITH  The Inheritor, The Heir 
98  ٱلْرَّشِيدُ AR-RASHEED  The Guide, Infallible Teacher 
99  ٱلْصَّبُورُ AS-SABOOR   The Forbearing, The Patient

Pick any you'd like :D